# Capture camera Image using ycbcr format

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture, color-space

I am using OpenCV to capture live from several cameras:

```
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(cameraNo)
```

Now, I need to convert images to YCbCr color space. I realized that I could use cvtColor to convert an image to another color space. However, the process is too expensive to do after capturing the image. [It includes a matrix transformation for every pixel](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html);

I wonder if there is a property setting or another way to perform the capturing (perhaps on hardware level) on the desired color space? Or the only way is to capture and convert?

Comment: OpenCV likely doesn't have this capability. Your platform may have other video capture APIs that do allow capture in formats other than RGB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, unfortunately you can't do that with OpenCV. The only way is to capture and convert.